# R Shiny applied to multiple histograms at once?

Tags: r, shiny

One method for showing multiple histograms from a data set is this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- mtcars

df1 %>%
  gather(key = "var", value = "value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = '', y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = "red", outlier.shape = 1) +
  facet_wrap(~ var, scales = "free") +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(title = "Boxplots of the numeric data")
```

That produces this result:
[image]

There are examples that show how to make one histogram interactive using R Shiny (for example: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/02/r-shiny-makes-your-data-alive/)

but I can't find any directions how to make a set of histograms interactive to change the number of bins using R Shiny, despite looking several places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want. I have adapted the code from the link you shared. Note that all that was needed is to first write a function that produces histograms for different binnings and then bind a shiny input to this function.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

# Function to perform my awesome analysis
# Returns a plot of the analyzed data
# @param x data frame containing the data to analyze
# @param bins integer parameter indicating the number of bins for the histogram. Default value  is 30.
my_hist <- function(x, bins = 30) {
  ggplot(x, aes(x=value)) +
    geom_histogram(bins=bins, fill='blue', alpha=0.7) +
    facet_wrap(~ variable, scales = "free") +
    ggtitle("Histograms") +
    xlab("Value") +
    ylab("Frequency")
}

# Shiny App User Interface
ui <- function(){
  fluidPage(
    # Application title
    titlePanel("Histogram of mtcars Data Set"),
    # Layout with a sidebar and a main panel
    sidebarLayout(
      # Panel with parameters controls
      sidebarPanel(
        sliderInput(
          inputId = "bins", label = "Number of bins:",
          min = 1, max = 50, value = 30
        )
      ),
      # Panel showing the results
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput(outputId = "my_plot")
      )
    )
  )
}

# Shiny App server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Convert mtcars to long format
  x <- gather(mtcars, key = "variable", value = "value", everything())
  
  # Construct reactive plot
  output$my_plot <- renderPlot({
    my_hist(x, input$bins)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```